# British use of a/an before words that begin with a consonant

Tags: grammar, british-english

I've noticed that during conversations on this website of whether to use "a" or "an" before words like "history" and "hypothesis" (words that begin with a consonant), those who are British tend to give a different answer than we Americans. They seem to generally respond that the proper grammar in that case is "an hypothesis" and "an historic event". Unfortunately, I noticed that one of my fellow Americans said that "a hypothesis" is much more common, and then proceeded to opine that "an hypothesis" is also correct, but "you risk sounding like a British snob". This does not seem like an appropriate comment, in my opinion, since it implies that the English people, whose language we are speaking, all sound like snobs if they abide by what they understand as the rules of proper English grammar.

So, that being said, I would be very interested to hear directly from an Englishman (preferably one who has some degree of upper level education in their language) about what exactly their grammar rules are on this subject, i.e. on when or if to use "an" before words beginning with a consonant. Does the rule apply to words that start with certain other letters besides "h"? If someone could quote directly from a British grammar manual, that would be quite helpful as well. I understand that this question in general has been responded to, but it appears that the respondent was not familiar with the British rules and customs, which, I would remind everyone, is the one and only place in the world that can legitimately tell others what the true grammatical rules of the English language really are. If there is a misunderstanding about this, more than likely it arises from we Americans' unconsciously and gradually departing from the correct English grammar, in favor of something that was easier and simpler.

I am specifically asking about the rules of "king's English", as they say.

Comment: Why do you think British customs are the only "legitimate" source of English language rules? The language wasn't *invented*, it formed organically. The vast majority of native English speakers do not live in Britain.

Comment: Don’t they actually say “an ‘istory”, where the h is silent and the word starts with a vowel sound?

Comment: It is the English language. The language was spoken in England for a thousand years before it was spoken anywhere else. It was created and formed entirely in England. No one but the Chinese can define how to properly speak Chinese. Imagine a Brit informing India that its language had changed, and if they continued using the form of their language they had used for millenia, they would be incorrect, or even "pompous" as someone said. 

The statement "the proper rules of the English language were decided in England" seems obvious to me. Please let an Englishman answer the question

Comment: What they say is what I am asking them. I'm interested to know. We should generally defer to the English on the rules of the English language, not assume that our way is right because it is common here. If you take an English exam in college, you can't make up grammar as you go along, on the grounds that it is in "common use". Grammar implies standardized rules that do not change, unless officially changed by a relevant authority. Common local dialect is distinct from a grammatical rule. There is also some distinction between American and British English, but it is their language.

Comment: Is this a troll?

Comment: Can someone who is competent to answer the question please answer the question, rather than offering criticisms of the question itself, or resorting to name calling? 

It is a legitimate question that pertains to the exact purpose that this website exists to serve.

Comment: Asking how those specific words are used in Britain is a reasonable question. The premise that Britain is the only valid arbiter of English grammar rules is not. The English language was not created and formed entirely in England. Modern English is only 500 years old, and has been spoken in countries outside England for hundreds of years, and it's really only within that period that the rules were formalised. Your second-last comment mentioned grammar rules being changed officially by a relevant authority, but there is no such authority even in England.

Comment: @GabrielM Your understanding of what grammar means and implies is **completely** wrong. Grammar is not dictated by authorities, nor “decided upon” by anyone, nor should speakers of one community defer to speakers of another for what the rules of their own grammar are. That is not how language and grammar work. Plus historical use is quite irrelevant to synchronic grammar. All languages evolve; English is no exception. There is nothing less ‘correct’ about AmE than BrE; they simply belong to different communities.

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find a duplicate, but there are lots of related questions at https://english.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=an%20with%20initial%20h: does one of the first few answer this?

Comment: Gabriel M 32 asked a very similar question over a year ago:  " How do you pronounce the H in “an historian”?"  Your question is only slightly different, so that it would be worth looking at some very comments and answers to that question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97830/discussion-between-nohat-and-gabriel-m).

Comment: Why all the down votes? We are all smarter than the askers, by default, or what!

Comment: This reinforces my suspicion that a down vote typically means "I don't know the answer, darn!"

Comment: The choice between 'a' and 'an' is not strictly a matter of _grammar_. When it gets to the grey areas, it is more akin to deciding whether to use single or double inverted commas around a simple quote. But the rules don't come under 'punctuation' either. // Simple and universal rules: until we get to some awkward cases, involving various words beginning with _h_ that are usually aspirated, pronunciation determines form: a car, a euro, an automobile, an heir. / Grey areas: some choose to say an hotel, an historian ... with or without aspiration. Enough people for it to be considered acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not limited to Great Britain.  We do it sometimes with some words in American English, too. It is not, for example, uncommon to see "an history," particularly in academia.  I remember my high school American history textbook was titled "*An* History of the United States," and I remember asking my teacher about the use of "an" instead of "a." She said the use of "an" instead of "a" was just with the word "history" in formal communication, but since then, I've seen and heard other examples of "an" being used in American English before not just "history" but other words with a hard H, too, but it's normally in an academic setting or in a documentary or something like that and it's with just the rare word.

I couldn't find my high school history textbook, but I did find this history book published in Philadelphia that uses "an" before "history":

> *Historical Collections, Vol. 1: Consisting of State Papers, and Other Authentic Documents, Intended as Materials for [an](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1333694571) History of the
>   United States of America*

Here is another example where "an" is used before "heroic" in *The United States Democratic Review, Volume 15*:

> "Those whom we have hitherto noticed were the men of [an](https://books.google.com/books?id=6ig4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA460&lpg=PA460&dq=%22Those%20whom%20we%20have%20hitherto%20noticed%20were%20the%20men%20of%20an%20heroic%20age.%22&source=bl&ots=TkD2IloJNS&sig=ACfU3U0eq6JJqXvDA6dGbUVjbBVezLp7Ew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwioqan2ipvkAhUJQK0KHbp5BCEQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Those%20whom%20we%20have%20hitherto%20noticed%20were%20the%20men%20of%20an%20heroic%20age.%22&f=false) heroic
>   age."

Answer (score 0):

The word 'an' is used before words beginning with 'H' because in speech the 'H' tends to be softened. In some British speech the 'H' is dropped out of habit or some custom. In either case such words sound as if they begin with vowels. The hypothesis then sounds like an eye-pothesis and so can afford an 'an' to introduce it. The basic rule is to have the 'a' distinct from the vowel at the start of such a word. 'An' serves this purpose when needed. A banana and an apple.

Comment: Is this an official grammatical rule? Are there British grammar books that describe and prescribe this particular rule? Does it apply to any and every word with a soft consonant? Can you think of any other examples? Why might this be common in Britain but unusual in America? Is it only uncommon in America, and as common in Canada, Australia, India, etc. as it is in Britain?

Answer (score 0):

No higher education to authorise my point of view but in other respects my background fits the bill for the OP as my early teachers were very strict on us speaking with " received pronunciation" during school , also elocution was part of the curriculum: The Queen's English!

As someone metioned in the comments , the manual likely has no section for this issue .
No recollection of anyone saying "an history" , often heard "an istory" but folk possessing what all Englishmen would agree is good diction would say "a history" .
This may be off topic as it is only regarding verbal usage but  IMO we must defer to the Queen herself in matters the textbooks do not cover , for example ; the pronunciation of scones really ought to rhyme with stones. 
By chance I do know a young lady who can find out if HM would verbalise "an hotel" and will comment back here once the info is in!

Comment: Rest assured, spoken English is on topic here!  I wouldn't much care how The Donald would verbalize "a hotel", and I am having difficulty thinking of a circumstance where HM would even be discussing one ;)

Comment: I agree with this answer completely. For millenia, the English language has flowed from the English monarch. It was indeed Alfred who first had the language codified and instructed to his people. His efforts are why we are speaking English today, and why either England or the United States exists today. I do, however, expect that there is some written guidance on this specific grammatical rule somewhere. I may have to buy one of H.W. and F.G. Fowler's books to find it. It would be fascinating to go through one of the written documents that were used to teach English in the days of Alfred.

Comment: I'm also very interested to hear back from you regarding the Queen's official ruling on this matter. :)